# Axios 'get' request returns string instead of object

Tags: jquery, ajax, object, get, axios

I'm having an issue with using axios.
The axios get request returns String instead of Object.
If I use Ajax request, It returns object.

I did console.log the `response.data` using axios
[image: axios get request response data]

Using the Ajax get request, the parentheses does not included with the return value but on the other hand, axios including the parentheses with return value. I'm assuming that is why returning value is String.

I'm looking for ways to get the returning data with Object.
Thank you.

## update

When I make the jQuery ajax get request, the query parameter creates jQuery############ like the image below and query parameter includes the parenthesis.
[image]

on the other hand, Axios get request does not includes the parenthesis in the query parameter. it just return as a string value.
[image]

is there an option to get rid of the parenthesis or any other way to not include parenthesis using axios.

## update2

I found the solution, why it was including the parenthesis.
my url was including the callback.. like "abcd/json.do?callback=?", after I removed the callback?.. it is working fine.

Comment: Does `JSON.parse(response.data)` help?

Comment: @vapurrmaid sorry for the late reply, and Thank you for the comment. `JSON.parse(response.data)` does not help, it was returning unexpected token which is parenthese,  I tried ` let obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));` it was returning same value.